# Argument subset in the tree package in R

Tags: r, tree

How does the argument *subset* in the *tree* package (specifically, in the *predict* function) does work? Predictions from this chunk:

```
install.packages("ISLR")
install.packages("tree")
library(ISLR)
library(tree)
data(Credit) # the dataset to use
train <- sample(1:nrow(Credit), nrow(Credit)/2) # training / test split
set.seed(1)
tree.Credit <- tree(Balance~.,Credit[train,]) # tree fit for Balance on training data (against all predictors)
tree.pred <- predict(object = tree.Credit, newdata = Credit[-train,]) # predictions on test data
length(tree.pred) # 200
```

are remarkably different from those produced by the following code (that appears logically equivalent to me!) as to their number:

```
tree.pred <- predict(object = tree.Credit, newdata = Credit,subset=-train) # predictions on test data
length(tree.pred) # 400 rather than 200!
```

Why? The two predict functions look logically equivalent to me.
How should I use the argument *subset* in the second predict to get the same results as the first?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the help for `predict.tree` you will see there is no argument `subset`. Unfortunately, R gives no warning in this case because `predict.tree` can take arguments from or to other methods. Basically you could pass anything to it.

You can subset the data beforehand, like you did. Why would you want to subset via predict?

Here is the help file:

```
predict.tree                 package:tree                 R Documentation

Predictions from a Fitted Tree Object

Description:

     Returns a vector of predicted responses from a fitted tree object.

Usage:

     ## S3 method for class 'tree'
     predict(object, newdata = list(),
             type = c("vector", "tree", "class", "where"), 
             split = FALSE, nwts, eps = 1e-3, ...)
    
Arguments: 

  object: fitted model object of class ‘tree’.  This is assumed to be the
          result of some function that produces an object with the same
          named components as that returned by the ‘tree’ function.

 newdata: data frame containing the values at which predictions are
          required.  The predictors referred to in the right side of
          ‘formula(object)’ must be present by name in ‘newdata’.  If
          missing, fitted values are returned.

    type: character string denoting whether the predictions are returned
          as a vector (default) or as a tree object.

   split: governs the handling of missing values. If false, cases with
          missing values are dropped down the tree until a leaf is reached
          or a node for which the attribute is missing, and that node is
          used for prediction. If ‘split = TRUE’ cases with missing
          attributes are split into fractional cases and dropped down each
          side of the split.  The predicted values are averaged over the
          fractions to give the prediction.

    nwts: weights for the ‘newdata’ cases, used when predicting a tree.

     eps: a lower bound for the probabilities, used if events of predicted
          probability zero occur in ‘newdata’ when predicting a tree.

     ...: further arguments passed to or from other methods.
```